Identify groups of sequential records
I have very simple table:
create table tmp(
    id int,
    source_id int,
    event_user varchar,
    event_date timestamp
);
 

and here is the data:
insert into tmp(id, source_id, event_user, event_date)
values (1, 1,  'A', now()),
       (2, 1,  'A', now()+interval '1 day'),
       (3, 1,  'B', now()+interval '2 day'),
       (4, 1,  'B', now()+interval '3 day'),
       (5, 1,  'A', now()+interval '4 day'),
       (6, 1,  'A', now()+interval '5 day'),
       (7, 1,  'A', now()+interval '6 day'),
       (8, 2,  'A', now()+interval '7 day'),
       (9, 2,  'B', now()+interval '8 day'),
       (10, 2,  'A', now()+interval '9 day'),
       (11, 2,  'B', now()+interval '10 day'),
       (12, 2,  'B', now()+interval '11 day') ;


(Here for the sake of simplicity I just added 1 day to 'now' timestamp in column event_date to show time sequence. In real case no any assumption about distribution of event_date could be made. Also columns 'id' and 'source_id' in real case are of type uuid.)
When I query this table:
select * from tmp
order by event_date;


I get:
initial data



id
source_id
event_user
event_date




1
1
A
03-05-2024


2
1
A
04-05-2024


3
1
B
05-05-2024


4
1
B
06-05-2024


5
1
A
07-05-2024


6
1
A
08-05-2024


7
1
A
09-05-2024


8
2
A
10-05-2024


9
2
B
11-05-2024


10
2
A
12-05-2024


11
2
B
13-05-2024


12
2
B
14-05-2024



Now, and here is the question, I need additional column (series_id) which identifies the groups of sequential (in order of event_date) records belonging to the same source_id and event_user.
so when I'll query I would like to get the following result:
expected result



id
source_id
SERIES_ID
event_user
event_date




1
1
1
A
03-05-2024


2
1
1
A
04-05-2024


3
1
2
B
05-05-2024


4
1
2
B
06-05-2024


5
1
3
A
07-05-2024


6
1
3
A
08-05-2024


7
1
3
A
09-05-2024


8
2
1
A
10-05-2024


9
2
2
B
11-05-2024


10
2
3
A
12-05-2024


11
2
4
B
13-05-2024


12
2
4
B
14-05-2024



I've tried window functions (rank(), dense_rank()), but didn't succeed, sure because records in expected groups do not have no common features except they're 'consequent' in time. May be it's a kind of 'gaps and islands' problem, but unfortunately I cant catch how to solve it.

Your suspicion is correct, this is a gaps and islands problem. Below is one approach to get the described results:
WITH
  tmp (id, source_id, event_user, event_date) AS (
    VALUES
      (1, 1, 'A', NOW()),
      (2, 1, 'A', NOW() + INTERVAL '1 day'),
      (3, 1, 'B', NOW() + INTERVAL '2 day'),
      (4, 1, 'B', NOW() + INTERVAL '3 day'),
      (5, 1, 'A', NOW() + INTERVAL '4 day'),
      (6, 1, 'A', NOW() + INTERVAL '5 day'),
      (7, 1, 'A', NOW() + INTERVAL '6 day'),
      (8, 2, 'A', NOW() + INTERVAL '7 day'),
      (9, 2, 'B', NOW() + INTERVAL '8 day'),
      (10, 2, 'A', NOW() + INTERVAL '9 day'),
      (11, 2, 'B', NOW() + INTERVAL '10 day'),
      (12, 2, 'B', NOW() + INTERVAL '11 day')
  ),
  breaks AS (
    SELECT
      id,
      event_user IS DISTINCT FROM LAG(event_user) OVER (
        PARTITION BY
          source_id
        ORDER BY
          event_date,
          event_user
      ) break,
      source_id,
      event_user,
      event_date
    FROM
      tmp
  )
SELECT
  id,
  source_id,
  COUNT(break) FILTER (
    WHERE
      break
  ) OVER (
    PARTITION BY
      source_id
    ORDER BY
      event_date
  ) AS series_id,
  event_user,
  event_date
FROM
  breaks
ORDER BY
  event_date;

This approach determines which rows start a new series and then assigns the series by counting the number of series starts within each source_id.

Thank you very much John. Nice solution. I got to the point similar to your 'breaks' part. But couldn't figure out how to propagate start of the series to consequent rows.
COUNT(break) FILTER (WHERE break ) OVER (PARTITION BY source_id ORDER BY event_date)
made my day :)
Thanks :)

The problem can be solved with slightly more concise query than JohnH's one.
select
  id,
  source_id,
  sum(break) over(partition by source_id
                  order by event_date, id) + 1 as serie_id,
  event_user,
  event_date
from (select
        *,
        (coalesce(lag(event_user) over(partition by source_id
                                       order by event_date, id),
                  event_user) <> event_user)::int as break
      from
        tmp)
;

db<>fiddle

Thank you Andrei for different look to the problem. Although both queries are logically equivalent, you sum ints while John counts booleans. now i've got understanding of using aggregates as window functions with an "order by" clause. useful tool :)
